# How can I make `flutter drive` show the browser when testing a web integration?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

When you use `flutter drive` on a simulator or device, you can actually see what is happening (see the textfields being filled, animations, etc)

But when I run the test on a browser, for example like this:

`flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart -d web-server --release --browser-name=chrome --web-port=8080`

You don't see anything. Just the result of the tests. So I'm now getting some failed tests and would love to `see` what the problem is (specially because they are not failing on the simulators.

Is there a flag I'm missing to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Next time I'll make sure to run `--help` before posting a question here

The flag to use is `--no-headless`